# Punctuation of a quote inside parentheses

Tags: academic-writing, citations, punctuation, quotes, mla

I was wondering how to properly format a quote inside parentheses in MLA. 
So far I have mostly used the third option, although the double parentheses seem a bit ugly.

example:

1) He directs his pleas to God ("cielos" Torre 226), whose help he seeks.

2) He directs his pleas to God ("cielos," Torre 226), whose help he seeks.

3) He directs his pleas to God ("cielos" (Torre 226)), whose help he seeks.

Comment: In #2, the comma belongs inside the quotes.  https://www.grammarly.com/blog/quotation-marks/

Comment: It may depend on whether your in the UK or elsewhere.

Comment: @StephenDaddona Ah, yes, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterJ Given that I am writing a paper at a German university, I am not exactly bound to either British or American style.

Comment: @PeterJ I am assuming that by MLA, OP is referring to ['the Modern Language Association of America'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Language_Association), who have a specific [style guide](https://www.mla.org/MLA-Style), and specify [American style](https://style.mla.org/punctuation-and-quotation-marks/) within it (but, they do [explain the different styles](https://style.mla.org/the-placement-of-a-comma-or-period-after-a-quotation/) as an academic matter on their website).

Comment: Just to stir the pot: *'4) He directs his please to God ("cielos" –Torre 226), whose help he seeks.'*

Comment: What is "cielos" in relation to the statement "He directs his pleas to God, whose help he seeks."?    I'm assuming "cielos" is a name or translation for God, but I do not know.   I do believe that in MLA, you should put your citation at the end of the sentance so "He directs his pleas to God ("cielos"), whose help he seeks (Torre 226).   Keep in mind MLA is an American English style guid so punctuation goes on the outside of parenthesis unless it's relevent to the statement in parentesis (I.E. see what I'm about to do right here?  Two periods.).